# Update information is outdated - error in updating a package

Tags: updates

`sudo apt-get update` gives me the following error:

```
 W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/scitools/ppa/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

    W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/scitools/ppa/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

    E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I have removed the `scitool` using `Synaptic package manager`, but it still gives me this error. How can I remove scitool from the apt-get update?

Comment: Did you remove the PPA you added for it? Open Software and Updates, go to Other Software and remove the scitools PPA.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although you have removed the `scitools` package, you haven't removed the PPA.

To remove the `scitools` PPA -

`sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:scitools/ppa`

Answer (score 0):

Else you can also use Y PPA Manager to off that PPA

Open your terminal and type/paste as

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/y-ppa-manager
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install y-ppa-manager
```

Then open that tool and you will see all your PPA's.